# How to add fixed underscore if value either exists or not?

Tags: html, css

I am having a html file and i wanted a underline for the value. For this I have added  tag as well as **text-decoration** in html. 
These *u* and *text-decoration* will work only if value exists. 
My requirement is to add a fixed underscore if value exists or doesnot exists (in **H1** tag of below example).

Html example is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Inline styles</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Text:
             <h1>Big Heading</h1>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try rephrasing for more clarity.

Comment: So you want to underline even when there's nothing to underline?

Comment: yes steve, I want fixed underline when there is text or no text.

Comment: @venkat then how do you know how much to underline? You could just have a fixed width div with a `border-bottom`.

Comment: Just for 30 characters, which is fixed.  Actually we are making sample pdf. so

Comment: your COULD fill it with spaces: `&nbsp;` for a cheat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add my comment as an answer, you can have a div with a fixed width and a `border-bottom` CSS attribute to give it an underline look.

```
div#underline {
    width:300px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

<div>Text: <div id="underline"></div></div>
```

Obviously, you can change the width to whatever you need, and can change the border style to suit. You could also use a non-breaking space (`&nbsp`) to give the div some further padding.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dphLum16/)